# Как исправить работу второй вложенности в меню (jquery)?

Tags: jquery

Есть выпадающее меню на jquery, нужно было добавить еще одну вложенность, я добавил: в пункте Отдых - Летний отдых - выпадающее подменю с месяцами, так вот при клике по иконке пункта Отдых(+) у меня открывается сразу подменю с месяцами, а хочу что бы оно сначала было закрытым, и лишь при клике по иконке Летний отдых(+) - открывалось, как это решить, не могу понять. Спасибо.

```js
$('.menu li').find('ul').parent().addClass('sub-menu');
$('.sub-menu').prepend('<span> + </span>');
$('.sub-menu').addClass('hide');
var menuShow = {
  show: function(post) {
    $('.sub-menu ul').slideUp();
    $(post).parent().removeClass('show');
    $(post).parent().addClass('hide');
  },
  hide: function(post) {
    $('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
    $('.sub-menu').addClass('hide');
    $('.sub-menu ul').slideUp();
    $(post).parent().find('ul').slideDown();
    $(post).parent().removeClass('hide');
    $(post).parent().addClass('show');
  }
};
$('.sub-menu span').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'sub-menu show') {
    menuShow.show(this);
  } else if ($(this).parent().attr("class") == 'sub-menu hide') {
    menuShow.hide(this);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 768px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1025;
}

.menu>li {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li.sub-menu {
  height: auto;
}

.menu li.sub-menu span {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: $accent-color;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: $accent-color;
  padding-left: 45px;
  img {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.menu>li>a {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  color: $accent-color;
  font-family: $Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
  color: lighten($accent-color, 10%);
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: rgb(246, 244, 245);
}

.menu li ul li:hover>a {
  color: lighten($accent-color, 10%);
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: rgb(246, 244, 245);
}

.menu ul li {
  line-height: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 60px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="placement.html">Размещение</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="single-room.html">1 местный номера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2-х местные номера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3-х местные номера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Путевки</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Питание</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Столовая</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ресторан</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Отдых</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="category.html">Летний отдых</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="info.html">Июнь</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Июль</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Август</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Межсезонье</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Активный отдых</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Полезная информация</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Услуги</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Трансфер</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Экскурсии</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ЖД/Авиа билеты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Парковка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Детская площадка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Танцевальная площадка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О пансионате</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Акции и скидки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Партнеры</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="contacts.html">Контакты</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Как добраться</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu li').find('ul').parent().addClass('sub-menu');
$('.sub-menu').prepend('<span> + </span>');

$('.sub-menu span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: попробуйте применить, увидите как меню работает при этом коде